# Existence of value inside nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check existence of a value in nested dictionary like below:

```
>>> x = {1:{'a':'b'}}
>>> 'a' in x.values()
False
```

I am still not able to get it. What is the correct way to check whether 'a' exists inside x or not?

Comment: you need `any('a' in v for v in x.values())`

Comment: Are you only checking for dict keys, or what about other types (e.g. in lists, as substring of value)? Should it handle more than one level of nesting?

Answer (score 3):

your example dictionary only has *one* key, and *one* value which is `{'a':'b'}`.

The value is a *dictionary*, so it's not the same type as `'a'` which is a string: no match.

To match this you would need a little more work:

```
>>> any('a' in v for v in x.values())
True
>>>
```

The loop checks for `'a'` as the key of the dictionaries values of `x` (and it's also the general case when your dictionary contains more than 1 element)

Answer (score 2):

Nested dictionaries can be thought of as trees. You can use something like a breadth first search

```
def bfs(key, tree): 
    if not isinstance(tree, dict):
        return False # this isn't a subtree, it's a leaf
    if key in tree:
        return True
    else:
        subtrees = [key for key in tree if isinstance(key, dict)]
        return any([bfs(key, subtree) for subtree in subtrees])
```

Caution, very large trees may blow the stack